# The distance $d(\mu_1,\mu_2):=\int \left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}\right|d\nu$ doesn't depend on $\nu$. Why?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I have the following problem. Define the variation distance as
$$d(\mu_1,\mu_2):=\int \left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}\right|d\nu,$$
where $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ e $\nu$ are probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, such that $\mu_1\ll \nu$ and $\mu_2\ll \nu$. I want to show that the distance $d$ doesn't depend on $\nu$.
My idea is to show that
$$\int \left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}\right|d\nu=\sup \sum_{i}|\mu_1(E_i)-\mu_2(E_i)|,$$
where the supremum is taken over all $\mathcal{F}$-measurable partitions $(E_i)_i$ of $\Omega$. The $"\geq"$ is easy:
$$\sup \sum_{i}|\mu_1(E_i)-\mu_2(E_i)|=\sup \sum_{i}\left|\int_{E_i}d\mu_1-\int_{E_i}d\mu_2\right|=\sup \sum_{i}\left|\int_{E_i}\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}d\nu\right|\leq$$
$$\leq \sup \sum_{i}\int_{E_i}\left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}\right|d\nu=\int \left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}\right|d\nu.$$
So we have
$$\int \left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}\right|d\nu\geq\sup \sum_{i}|\mu_1(E_i)-\mu_2(E_i)|.$$
Now, I don't know how to show the other inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ let $\lambda=\nu_1+\nu_2$. Then, for $\nu=\nu_1$ as well as $\nu=\nu_2$ we have  $\int \left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}\right|d\nu=\int \left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}\right|\frac {d\nu} {d\lambda} d\lambda$. Bring $\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}$ inside the integral to see that  $\int \left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\nu}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\nu}\right|d\nu=\int \left|\frac{d\mu_1}{d\lambda}-\frac{d\mu_2}{d\lambda}\right|d\lambda$. Hence, the left side is the same for $\nu=\nu_1$ and  $\nu=\nu_2$